# How to keep transparent hugepages config after reboot?

Tags: centos, huge-pages

I used the below way to disable transparent hugepages. But they are restored (enabled again) after reboot.

```
echo never > /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/defrag
echo no > /sys/kernel/mm/redhat_transparent_hugepage/khugepaged/defrag
```

How to keep those modified after reboot?

Answer (score 4):

resolved^_^ Add them to the end of /etc/rc.local

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/grub.conf`. 
Add:

```
transparent_hugepage=never
```

to the "kernel" line.